# How do mixed models bypass the overflow inside the integration?

Tags: mixed-model, numerical-integration

In a mixel model, when you try to maximize the likelihood, you have to integrate over the random effects.

This means that you cannot take logs, since what would normally be a product of individual probability masses, is now an integral, and the log of integrals does not decompose nicely.

How then is this handled numerically?

I've tried searching online, and all I found was that you use Gaussian quadrature to estimate the integral. I don't see how this answers the question, it just moves the goalpost. If you use quadrature, your likelihood is still a sum of products, i.e.

$$\int \prod ... dx \ \ \text{becomes} \ \ \sum \prod ... $$

and taking the log of the RHS is still not going to solve the numerical overflow that can occur when calculating the $\prod$ inside each sum!

Imagine you have 10 million pieces of data. $\prod$ over that data is going to be an insanely difficult number to handle. How is this solved, when the integral prevents logging?

Comment: This is why the [EM algorithm](https://stephens999.github.io/fiveMinuteStats/intro_to_em.html) is used.